# Add <br> above submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a small form where a user can select a series of files.  I have a submit button, and another button while creates another file element.  All I want to do is pop up each new file element above the submit button rather than below the submit button.  This is what I have thus far.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP']);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="upload_form">
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="button" onclick = 'javascript: add()' value="ADD ANOTHER FILE" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function add()
{
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var foo = document.getElementById("upload_form");
foo.appendChild(br);
    form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type="file";
    input.name="file[]";
    form.appendChild(input);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parentElement.insertBefore(newChild, existingChild)`:

This method will add the new elements above the "add button" instead of above the submit button like you specified.

HTML:

```
<input id="addbutton" type="button" onclick = 'javascript: add()' value="ADD ANOTHER FILE" />
```

Javascript:

```
    var form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
    var addButton = document.getElementById('addbutton');

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    form.insertBefore(br, addButton);

    form = document.getElementById("upload_form");

    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type="file";
    input.name="file[]";
    form.insertBefore(input, addButton);
```

It looks like your form may have a few layout problems. It is also probably best not to use `<br>` but instead a wrapper element for each row with CSS styling.  That way you can also only use `insertBefore` once (for the wrapper) and it is less confusing.

Also, if you aren't aware of it you should look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com). This kind of DOM manipulation is once of its primary strengths.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insertBefore`, it inserts a node as a child, right before an existing child, which you specify.

As you want to insert before `submit` button, use this code

```
form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
var foo = document.getElementById("submit"); 
form.insertBefore(br,foo);
```